# how to launch NetLogo from Terminal if there are extensions loaded

Tags: netlogo

Before version 6 I was able to launch NetLogo from Terminal like this:

java -jar /Applications/NetLogo\ 6.0.4/Java/netlogo-mac-app.jar

and it worked fine even with extensions, but nowadays it seems that NL is unable to find even bundled extensions when launched from terminal...

is there something I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: I don`t have experiences on MacOS, but under windows whenever I had issues with NetLogo not finding extensions two solutions worked. Either copy all extensions folders that are used within your model from the NetLogo installation folder into the folder where your model (*.nlogo file) is located. Or copy your model and all related files into the subfolder "models" of the NetLogo installation (".../NetLogo 6.0.2/app/models/").

Comment: apparently none of those works on MacOSX.. your second option is evident from my image, the CSV Example is already in model library...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cd /Applications/NetLogo\ 6.0.4
java -jar Java/netlogo-6.0.4.jar
```

now go to

> File > Open...

and pick your model to start

that worked for me.

You have to run the jar from the same location as application starts from.

Comment: I see what you mean, NL wants to be in the same folder where also the extension folder is... what if that's not the case? can I set the path to the extension folder?

Comment: yes, set `-Dnetlogo.extensions.dir=` from the command line. But I recommend being in the directory unless you have some reason for automating that requires further abstracting locations.